# AudioTrack only playing noise instead of recorded voice

Tags: java, android, audiotrack

I want to play recorded voice using audio track but its making noise I tried different techniques but unable to solve this issue.
I Changed:
frequency rate, Audio Format Channel Audio Formate Encoding

```
  public class PlayAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
   
        PlayAudio playTask;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFolder/";
        String myfile = path + "filename" + ".wav";
        File recordingFile = new File(myfile);      
        boolean isRecording = false,isPlaying = false;
    
        int frequency = 44100   ,channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
        int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                isPlaying = true;      
                int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency,channelConfiguration,audioEncoding);
                short[] audiodata = new short[bufferSize / 4];        
                try {
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(recordingFile)));
                    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency,
                            channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize,
                            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);        
                    audioTrack.play();
                    while (isPlaying && dis.available() > 0) {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (dis.available() > 0 && i < audiodata.length) {
                            audiodata[i] = dis.readShort();
                            i++;
                        }
                        audioTrack.write(audiodata, 0, audiodata.length);
                    }
                    dis.close();
    
               //     startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);
              //      stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
    
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: No, I think Audio Track is depreciated, May be this is the reason

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the whole problem, but part of your problem is that you're treating the wav file as if all of it is audio data. In fact, there is a fair amount of meta-data in there. See http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ for more information.

The safest thing to do is to parse the file until you find data block, then read the data block, and then stop (because often there's meta-data that comes after the data block too.

Here's some rough code to give you the idea.

```
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        // First find the data chunk

        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];

        // Read first 4 bytes.
        // (Should be RIFF descriptor.)
        // Assume it's ok
        is.read(bytes);

        // First subchunk will always be at byte 12.
        // (There is no other dependable constant.)
        is.skip(8);

        for (;;) {
            // Read each chunk descriptor.
            if (is.read(bytes) < 0) {
                break;
            }

            String desc = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII");

            // Read chunk length.
            if (is.read(bytes) < 0) {
                break;
            }

            int dataLength = (
                    (bytes[0] & 0xFF) |
                            ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                            ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                            ((bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24));

            long length = getUnsignedInt(dataLength);

            if (desc.equals("data")){
                // Read 'length' bytes
```

...

```
public static long getUnsignedInt(int x) {
        return x & 0x00000000ffffffffL;
}
```